# How do I print these two images next to each other and not one above another?

Tags: netbeans-8

I have been able to print both images one on top of another but I also need to print them beside each other. Can someone please help me? (I need to be able to print it under what I have already got)

[image]

Code for Square and triangle one on top of another

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.print(" *");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 5-i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.print(" *");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply combine the two outermost for loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        System.out.print(" *");
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= 5 - i+1; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int k = 1; k <= i+1; k++) {
        System.out.print(" *");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
System.out.println("");
```

Comment: Note: all references to 'i' inside second of the two outermost for loop replaced with 'i+1' since second outermost for loop start at i=1 not i=0.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This has helped a lot.